# Sweet Alert 2 and Socket.io use result of an emit in preConfirm

Tags: javascript, socket.io, promise, sweetalert

I'm using [SWAL2 preConfirm()](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request) function in a sweet alert to test if an ID is ok server side... using `socket.emit()` with [acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)

I would like to be able to use `Swal.showValidationMessage("Some error")` depending on the server's error returned ...

But the preConfirm function only works with promises functions, meaning using `.then().catch()...`

The only workaround I found is an ugly one :

```
 Swal.fire({
  title: 'ID ?',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,  
  confirmButtonText:'Go',
  cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (id) => {
    if(id.trim().length === 3){
      socket.emit('isID', id, this.props.name, (r) => {

        // Here I have the answer from the server so I can test the returned
        // value and eventualy set an error which I couldn't if I didn't put the "TRICK" part ( see below )
        if(r === 'ok'){
          Swal.fire({
            title: `ok !!`,
            type: 'success'
          });
        } else {
           Swal.showValidationMessage("Server error !");
        }
      });

      Swal.showValidationMessage(""); // --> HERE IS THE 'TRICK'

    } else {
      Swal.showValidationMessage(" it's 3 letters for an id mate !");
    }
  },
});
```

Let me explain : using `Swal.showValidationMessage("")` keeps the sweet alert open in order to later fulfill it with the server error ...

The problem is if there's a low connection the empty message can be seen even if the server's answer gonna be correct

Any advices on how to improve this ?

( In the code snippet below I use a promise with a timeout to mimics a long server answer )

```js
Swal.fire({
      title: 'ID ?',
      input: 'text',
      showCancelButton: true,  
      confirmButtonText:'Go',
      cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
      preConfirm: (id) => {
        if(id.trim().length === 3){
          let r = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              Swal.fire({
                title: `Server answered OK no need to error message !`,
                type: 'success'
              });
            }, 2000);
          });
       
          Swal.showValidationMessage(""); // --> HERE IS THE 'TRICK'
            
        } else {
          Swal.showValidationMessage(" it's 3 letters for an id mate ;)");
        }
      },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.0.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** Bump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another custom promise function that call socket.emit like:

```js
emit(event, data,prop) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if (!this.socket) {
           reject('No socket connection.');
       } else {
           this.socket.emit(event, data, prop, (response) => {
              resolve(response);
           });
       }
   });
 }
```

And then your code will be like this:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'ID ?',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,  
  confirmButtonText:'Go',
  cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (id) => {
    if(id.trim().length === 3){
      return emit('isID', id, this.props.name)
      .then((r) => {
        if(r === 'ok'){
          return r;
        } else {
           Swal.showValidationMessage("Server error !");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(
          `Request failed: ${error}`
        )
      })
    } else {
      Swal.showValidationMessage(" it's 3 letters for an id mate !");
    }
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: `ok !!`,
        type: 'success'
      });
  }
})
```

Hope helps.

Comment: I must try this !! Seems great ! I finally got an answer for this ! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

With @Mike85's help, here is what works :

```js
const gonnaWork = false;
const promiseWrapper = (id) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       //this.socket.emit(id, data, data2, (response) => {
       //   resolve(response);
       //});
       setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(gonnaWork ? 'ok' : 'ko');
       }, 2000);
   });
}

Swal.fire({
  title: 'ID ?',
  input: 'text',
  showCancelButton: true,  
  confirmButtonText:'Go',
  cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: (id) => {
    if(id.trim().length === 3){
      return promiseWrapper(id)
      .then((r) => {
        if(r === 'ok'){
          return r;
        } else {
           Swal.showValidationMessage("Server error !");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        Swal.showValidationMessage(
          `Request failed: ${error}`
        )
      })
    } else {
      Swal.showValidationMessage(" it's 3 letters for an id mate !");
    }
  },
  allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading()
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: `ok !!`,
        type: 'success'
      });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.0.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```